# QGraphicsScene with a QGLWidget as the viewport not rendering QSvgRenderer antialiasing correctly

Tags: linux, qgraphicsscene, qt4.8, qglwidget

first I try to describe what I want:
I want a (qt 4.8 - based [can but must not]) Opengl-able context set in the background somewhere. Then the first layer has an Image with an transparent ROUND!! hole where you can see the OpenGl context. and on top of that static image there are buttons for some logic.

What I did:
I try to render a Svg with the QSvgRenderer in front of an opengl scenery.
The OpenGl Scenery is drawn in a QGraphicsView with an QGLWidget as Viewport.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GraphicsView view;
    //trying to get the anitaliasing to work
    view.setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform );

    QGLWidget* glwid = new QGLWidget( QGLFormat( QGL::SampleBuffers | QGL::AlphaChannel | QGL::Rgba ));

    //Set Multisampling
    QGLFormat frm = glwid->format();
    glwid->format().setSamples(4);
    glwid->setFormat(frm);

    //set the GlViewport
    view.setViewport(glwid); //--> SvgRendering works with no anti aliasing but glRendering does.

    //view.setViewport(new QWidget);  //--> SvgRendering with Antialiasing works

    view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::SmartViewportUpdate);
    view.setScene(new OpenGLScene(view.rect()));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();

}
```

The Scene Looks like this

```
#include "openglscene.h"
#include "PotentioMeter.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#ifndef GL_MULTISAMPLE
#define GL_MULTISAMPLE  0x809D
#endif


OpenGLScene::OpenGLScene(const QRectF &rect)
    : m_backgroundColor(0, 170, 255)
    , m_distance(1.4f)
{
    //One or more Widgets And buttons with svg special Looking (because of scaling)
    PotentioMeter* pm = new PotentioMeter( );
    pm->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    pm->resize(500,500);

    addWidget(pm);

    QPushButton *backgroundButton = new QPushButton(tr("Choose background color"));
    connect(backgroundButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setBackgroundColor()));
    backgroundButton->move(900,20);
    addWidget(backgroundButton);

    //Where should be the gl things drawn
    rGlViewport = QRectF(100, 100,rect.width()/2,rect.height()/2);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    const int UPDATE_RATE_25HZ_IN_MSEC = 40;
    timer->start(UPDATE_RATE_25HZ_IN_MSEC);
}

//dummy gl drawing function
void OpenGLScene::pyramid(QColor* color)
{
  glScalef(0.5,0.5,0.5);
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(++angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
  glColor4f(color->redF(),color->greenF(),color->blueF(),1);
  glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.f, 0.0f );
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f );
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glColor4f(color->redF(),color->greenF(),color->blueF(),1);
  glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
  glColor4f(color->redF(),color->greenF(),color->blueF(),1);
  glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glColor4f(color->redF(),color->greenF(),color->blueF(),1);
  glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
  glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();

}

void
OpenGLScene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF & f)
{
  //check painter
  if (painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL
      && painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2)
    {
      qWarning(
          "OpenGLScene: drawBackground needs a QGLWidget to be set as viewport on the graphics view");
      return;
}

  //check viewport
  if (f != myViewport)
    {
      myViewport = f;
    }

  //desperately trying to do antialiasing
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);

  glClearColor(m_backgroundColor.redF() + .2, m_backgroundColor.greenF() - .2, m_backgroundColor.blueF() + .2, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1000.0, 1000.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();

  glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

  glViewport(rGlViewport.x(), rGlViewport.y(), rGlViewport.width(),
      rGlViewport.height());

  //draw some gl stuff
  pyramid(&m_backgroundColor);

  glViewport(myViewport.x(), myViewport.y(), myViewport.width(),
  myViewport.height());

  glPopMatrix();

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPopMatrix();

}

void
OpenGLScene::setBackgroundColor()
{
  const QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(m_backgroundColor);
  if (color.isValid())
    {
      m_backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

GL but no AA:
[image: GL but no AA]

No GL but AA:
[image: No GL but AA]

The Big Problem is now that when trying to render OpenGl and the Svg at the same time, either Opengl is not rendered - because of the missing context and the svg is rendered perfectly, or the opengl is rendered and the svg is not antialiased correctly.
So any ideas to get the antaliasing randering correctly?

The complete Project (ready for eclipse - made with cmake)
and Screenshots 
and a prebuild executable
is in the link here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/giqynqfuq2yl8li/SampleCode.zip

Comment: did you ever solve this?